# Is it still valid to zig-zag an opponent through a wall for multiple hits?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, forced-movement

[An old D&D 4e trick](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3450/559) is to use forced movement to zig-zag your opponent through a wall effect multiple times for multiple hits. As I understand it, the Wall of Fire power specifically has been errata'd to allow only one hit per turn.

Can you, in general, still zig-zag someone through a wall for multiple hits? Additionally, are there any powers left which will actually allow this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By the spirit of the arcanist playtest, no. Formally, yes, depending on power text.**

While [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3455/2788) covers wall of fire specifically, the intent as stated was to reduce forced movement abuse. However, given that the [PHB FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1396/~/faq-for-the-player%27s-handbook!) hasn't been updated nor has the compendium been updated with any formal errata... ask your DM. This is clearly a situation where they're gradually migrating zone damage away from forced movement cheese, but haven't released formal errata to cover it.