# Can a creature use an Immediate Interrupt (Trigger: Enemy Movement) against his own forced Move Action?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, forced-movement, immediate-actions, interrupt

If a creature has an Immediate Interrupt action with a Trigger: Enemy Movement - can the creature use an ability that forcefully pulls the target - then immediately after pulling the target, invoke the Immediate Interrupt Ability because the enemy, "Moved".

In other words, if a creature forces an enemy to move, does the creature then have the ability to use an Immediate Interrupt action which is triggered by Enemy Movement? Since the movement was forced, and the enemy didn't make the action to move, does this not satisfy the Immediate Interrupt's requirements?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Interesting question...

Comment: Also, if you go down this route, be prepared for your players to ... amuse themselves with forced movement and zones. :)

Comment: Well, I tend to play Defender-Controller roles myself; and I thoroughly enjoy controlling the battlefield. Understanding Interrupts, Forced-Movement, and Triggers is very important for me and my GM.

Comment: You may want to check out the wall of fire [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3450/760) on the site, as wizards is basically nerfing multiple-damage per forced movement. Consider building around the paragon agile opportunist instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, but not for the reason you think: creatures cannot take interrupts on their own turns.**

An interrupt action has been explicitly defined as something which must occur on some other creature's turn (PHB, 268) (much to the chagrin of the Juggernaut in my party who can't use her "on bloodied" interrupt when she's bloodied from ongoing damage or auras or any of the other bloody things that tend to bloody her on her turn.).

While an enemy could certainly use a *free* pull and an interrupt triggered off enemy movement, the specific combination you outlined above is invalid.

More literature and discussion [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19656758/Immediate_actions_during_your_turn), [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19396078/Biggest_Clear_Cut_Rules_Mistakes_Compendium&post_num=3#329827918), and [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=120).

Quoth PHB via [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19686342/Rules_Q38;A_FAQ__ask_a_simple_question&post_num=9919#514363497):

> The actual PHB p.268 reads: "If you haven’t taken an immediate action since the end of your last turn, you can take one when a trigger allows you to. You can’t take an immediate action on your own turn."

Comment: Oh - no, I may have missed the dead page numbers on my first read. Sorry, I am new to the website. Thank you very much for the help on this one. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No worries mate. As a general thing, it's usually good form to wait a day or so before marking an answer as accepted, because more and better answers (or better articulations) may arrive. Here... probably not so much, but for future reference. You *are* coming back with more questions, right? :) ::ominous loom:: (prior comments flagged for deletion as obsolete.)

Comment: I'll be back to this site often. When you have a group of players and a GM who love the technicalities of this game - and love controlling - I have a feeling there will be many of these discussions left to come.

Comment: I thought forced movement didn't trigger interrupts, but it's been awhile since I've been in that part of the PHB.

Comment: Interrupts can trigger off anything. It's all about the specific wording of the trigger. Precedent: the attack granted by agile opportunist from being slid next to an enemy.